# Disable any incoming external links to a Excel Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two workbooks. Say test1.xlsx and test2.xlsx and have saved them in the same directory.

I write a formula to create an external link in cell A1 of sheet1 of test2.xlsx.

Example:
In the A1 cell of sheet1 of test2.xlsx I write =[test1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1 and press enter. It copies the corresponding cell content of test1.xlsx into test2.xlsx

I don't want this formula to be executed. I want that my workbook "test1.xlsx" shouldn't be accessed by any other external workbook i.e. no one can provide an external reference to test1.xlsx and if provided, it should return any error say "!#REF"

I am using Excel 2010.

It will be quite helpful for me to know exactly what are the events taking place in test1.xlsx

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the behavior requested, but you could do this:

Password-protect test1. The user will be prompted for the password when the formula is entered.

If the password is correctly entered, the formula(s) will execute, but the users will be prompted for the password to update links each time test2 is opened.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this. But, this is not my use case. I need a mechanism which can either track or stop the incoming external reference.